# Ordering by inherited field

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

Let's say, we have some entity - Order.

- Order has field "client" of type Client
- We have another entity - SpecialClient, that is subclass of Client. (InheritanceType is Joined).
- In SpecialClient class, there is field "specialField".

Is it possible to get from database list of orders, ordered by that "specialField", if we can assume that all of order "clients" are of type SpecialClient?

edit - I want to do it, using Criteria API

I've tried something like:

```
qCriteria.orderBy(qBuilder.asc(qRoot.get("client")
.as(SpecialClient.class).get("specialField")))
```

, 
but fragment:

```
as(SpecialClient.class).get("specialField"))
```

is not legal because of type returned by `as()` method

Comment: What is your query? "SELECT o FROM Order o ORDER BY o.client.specialField" ? That won't work because specialField is not a field of Client. But you could cast the client field in JPQL ... and have you tried that?

Comment: I'm using Criteria API

Comment: which has no relevance to the problem .... you can do the same things in JPQL as you can in Criteria. The issue is that you cannot refer to some field that is in a subclass unless you cast ... like in Java. So do the cast (in Criteria)

Comment: I've tried, but I don't know how to do it with ordering (`qCriteria.orderBy()`)

Comment: so present what you have tried ... IN THE QUESTION, not in the comments. The keyword for casting is TREAT, so there is a method on Criteria for that

Comment: presented, I probably misunderstand `as()`
That "treat" seems to be solution, just have to upgrade JPA version. Thanks :)